# Comparing definitions of cotangent complex

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, simplicial-stuff, derived-categories, cotangent-complex

Consider the following two ways of defining the cotangent complex of a ring map $R \rightarrow A$ (Let $P^{\bullet} \rightarrow A$ be a polynomial resolution):

1. As the complex $\Omega^1_{P^{\bullet}/R} \otimes_{P^{\bullet}} A$
2. As the complex associated (via Dold-Kan) to the simplicial $R$-module $\Omega^1_{P^{\bullet}/R}$

This is described in section 2.1 of: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03261.pdf

*Are these complexes quasi-isomorphic? If so, why?*

(In the reference above, this is claimed to be a consequence of the fact that $P^{\bullet} \rightarrow B$ is a weak equivalence of simplicial $R$-algebras, but I don't see why it follows from this).

Comment: This is best seen by considering the $\infty$-category of simplicial commutative $R$-algebras, $CAlg_{R}^{\Delta}$, which is obtained from the simplicial model category of simplicial commutative $R$-algebras, $SCR_{R}$, by inverting the weak equivalences, so they become equivalences in the $\infty$-category. Thus, we literally have that $P_{\bullet} \simeq A$ in $CAlg_{R}^{\Delta}$, An $R$-algebra polynomial resolution, $R \rightarrow P_{\bullet} \rightarrow A$, we have $\Omega^{1}_{P_{\bullet}/R} \otimes_{P_{\bullet}} A \simeq \Omega^{1}_{P_{\bullet}/R}$ in $D(R)$.

Comment: Additionally, I really like your username :)

Comment: @LPK Thanks for your help and the kind words! Actually it is your last sentence that I'm unsure about. Do I understand correctly that $\Omega^1_{P^{\bullet}/R} \otimes_{P^{\bullet}} A$ is a tensor product of simplicial modules, which is taken "levelwise"? And that the key step is replacing $P^{\bullet}$ with $A$ in the argument of the functor $\Omega^1_{P^{\bullet}/R} \otimes_{P^{\bullet}} -$? If so, shouldn't there be some argument that $\Omega^1_{P^{\bullet}/R} \otimes_{P^{\bullet}} -$ respects weak equivalences, and hence extends to a functor on the $\infty$-category?

Comment: Yes, you're correct that $\Omega_{P^{\bullet}/R} \otimes_{P^{\bullet}} A$ has $n$-simplices given by $\Omega_{P_{n}/R} \otimes_{P_{n}} A$. Maybe the right thing to say is the following: since $P^{\bullet}$ is a polynomial $R$-algebra resolution, this means that $P^{n}$ is a Polynomial $R$-algebra, and hence for each $n$, $\Omega^{1}_{P_{n}/R}$ is free as a $P_{n}$-module. This means the tensor product is derived, so we can calculate it using the Tor spectral sequence. Comparing the E_2 term to the target of convergence we see that the desired simplicial modules have the same homotopy groups.